# Python3 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python-3.x

Senhores, iniciando em python e quebrando a cabeça aqui...
tenho um arquivo cvs com centenas de linhas, (sei que que pandas seria o ideal pra isso, mas como disse estou iniciando, e preciso entender alguns conceitos antes).
E nesse arquivo preciso ler apenas as ultimas 100 linhas, e algumas colunas (até aqui ok, consegui fazer), porém o csv me devolve uma lista de listas e eu desejo unir todas as listas em apenas uma tipo isso, mas em inteiros.
obs.: A função map não está convertendo para inteiros
Ex.: lista = [['1','2','3'], ['4','5','6']]
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
segue o programa abaixo:

````py
import csv
with open('arquivo.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as arq:
    linhas = csv.reader(arq, delimiter=',')
    dados = list(linhas)
    dados = dados[1730:1830]
    map(int, dados)

    print([dados[2:17] for dados in dados]) # Aqui imprime corretamente da coluna 2 à 17
    print(sum([dados[2:17] for dados in dados])) # mas se eu tentar juntar aqui me retorna o erro citado acima.```
````

Comment: `map(int, dados)`, essa linha de código está fazendo nada. Ela não modifica `dados`, ela possui um retorno que precisa ser atribuído à uma variável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi basicamente devido a uma chamada inconsistente à função `sum`:

```
sum([dados[2:17] for dados in dados])
```

Se verificar a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>
> *Sums `start` and the items of an `iterable` from left to right and returns the total. `start` defaults to 0. The iterable’s items are normally numbers, and the `start` value is not allowed to be a string.*

Onde é possível verificar que, por omissão, o valor de `start` é 0. Você tem uma lista de listas, algo como `[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]`, então na primeira iteração dentro da função `sum` será executado a operação equivalente a `result = start + ['1', '2']`; como `start` é 0, basicamente você estará somando um `int` com uma `list`, dando o erro citado.

Uma forma simples de contornar isso seria definindo o valor inicial, `start`, como uma lista vazia, assim a operação equivalente a `result = [] + ['1', '2']`. Para tal, basta definir o valor de segundo argumento da função `sum`:

```
sum([dados[2:17] for dados in dados], [])
```

---

Algumas ressalvas sobre o seu código:

- Ao fazer `dados = list(linhas)` você armazenará todo o conteúdo do arquivo em memória. Se o arquivo lido for muito grande isso poderá travar a aplicação. Para cada linha do arquivo será criado um objeto `list` e para cada item da lista um objeto `str`, o que demandaria ainda muito mais memória do que o próprio tamanho do arquivo;
- A linha `map(int, dados)` não tem utilidade alguma no código da forma que está. O que a função `map` faz é retornar um iterador que aplica a função definida sobre os elementos do iterável informado, neste caso aplica `int` nos itens de `dados`. A função não modifica os parâmetros, então se você não atribuir o retorno da função em nenhuma variável ela estará em vão no código;

Para contornar o primeiro, você pode trabalhar diretamente sobre os iteradores, sem carregar tudo em memória. Por exemplo, `linhas` será um iterável com as linhas do seu arquivo, como você quer apenas as linhas entre 1730 e 1830, basta você pegar essa parte do iterável:

```
linhas_que_voce_quer = itertools.islice(linhas, 1730, 1830)
```

Isso retornará outro iterável, mas apenas para as linhas que você precisa. Todas as outras não serão carregadas na memória (não ao mesmo tempo, pelo menos). A partir dele você pode utilizar a função `map` para converter para inteiros e a função `sum` para unir, ou utilizar a função `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, que também faz essa unificação.